# Laravel custom auth based on json data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make auth based on third party api in laravel. not storing or using data from my local db. Here I am keeping api response data as an array just for visualization . It shows error **Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php** . How can I fix that. I also made R&D on it. Thanks in advance

```
    $user = [
        'status' => '200',
        'token' => 'aWsIpvOEZfv4sfSRUGS2dDeGw7',
        'id' => '12454545412',
        'user' => [
            'name' => 'xyz',
            'email' => 'xyz@gmail.com',
            'phone' => '12344787',
        ],
    ];

    $user = json_encode($user);
    Auth::login($user);
    return redirect( '/home' );
```

Comment: Why do you need to authenticate when you are not validating user data? And if you are validating the user, you should have a eloquent model for the users with extending Authenticatable class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I did not mention  ** validating user data** section. When It get match data , that time api responses mentioned json data which I keep as an array for visualization . How can I make auth with this data ?

Comment: Are you storing users in the database? Also, if you want to authenticate this data, you should create one helper class with extending Authenticatable class and assign these properties to it.

Comment: No I am not keeping this in user db and I don't want this

Comment: Can you please make this solution as answer. I am not getting your solution

Comment: Did you try `Auth::login($user['user']);`?

Comment: Yes but not works ........

Comment: @Mithun Please see the below answer. As per my thought, it should be best fit for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create User class as a dummy model if you prefer.

```
namespace App\Helpers; // depends on you 

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class AuthUser extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

And you can use like this:

```
$user = [
    'id' => '12454545412',
    'name' => 'xyz',
    'email' => 'xyz@gmail.com',
    'phone' => 1234564897,
    'token' => 'aWsIpvOEZfv4sfSRUGS2dDeGw7' // if you need in your user Object
];
$user = new AuthUser($user);
Auth::login($user);
dd(auth()->user());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It works but 1 little thing. If I use in a controller **public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }** It does not allow that auth

Comment: Did you register this middleware in app/Http/Kernet.php?